# Google ORTools - Nodes that can't share the same route

Tags: or-tools

I need to solve this routing problem: two nodes cannot share the same route.

I.e.: if vehicle stop at node A, it shouldn't be allowed to stop also at node B, that means that node A and node B cannot be on the same route.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Fabio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```py
routing.solver().Add(routing.VehicleVar(index_a) != routing.VehicleVar(index_b))
```

Comment: Awesome! Great, Mizux

Comment: I have tried this solution, however the result was not consistent. Is this a soft constraint?

Comment: @KK2491 no `routing.olver().Add()` will add a hard constraint to the underlying CP solver.