# Google ORTools - Nodes that can't share the same route (again)

Tags: c#, or-tools

In reference to my previous request [prievousRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405089/google-ortools-nodes-that-cant-share-the-same-route), I need help for a further issue: a route cannot have more than two work category at the same time.

**Conditions as follows:**

- *Node A: work category 1 and work category 2*
- *Node B: work category 3*
- *Node C: work category 1*
- *Node D: work category 2*

**Solutions:**

- Depot > A > C > Depot, is a valid route
- Depot > B > D > Depot, is a valid route
- Depot > A > B > Depot, is **NOT** a valid route
- Depot > A > D > Depot, is a valid route
- Depot > B > C > D > Depot, is **NOT** a valid route

Hence, the first two work categories on vehicle must exclude the addition of any other node with different work category.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Best, Fabio

######################### EDIT #######################

... old code with a bad attempt to have dynamic work types  ...

######################### EDIT 2 #######################

To understand something I simplify the context: only 3 work types then

```
//work types for each nodes
long[][] worksMatrix = new long[5][];
worksMatrix[0] = new long[] { 0 };
worksMatrix[1] = new long[] { 1, 2 };
worksMatrix[2] = new long[] { 3 };
worksMatrix[3] = new long[] { 1 };
worksMatrix[4] = new long[] { 2 };

//1: meccanica (car mechanics work), 2: gomme (tires change\repair), 3: cristalli (car glass repair)

int meccanicaCallBack = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback((long fromIndex) =>
{
    var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
    var nodeWorkTypes = model.WorksMatrix[fromNode];

    if (nodeWorkTypes.Contains(1))
        return 1;
    return 0;
});

routing.AddDimension(meccanicaCallBack, 0, 100, true, "meccanica");

int gommeCallBack = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback((long fromIndex) =>
{
    var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
    var nodeWorkTypes = model.WorksMatrix[fromNode];

    if (nodeWorkTypes.Contains(2))
        return 1;
    return 0;
});

routing.AddDimension(gommeCallBack, 0, 100, true, "gomme");

int cristalliCallBack = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback((long fromIndex) =>
{
    var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
    var nodeWorkTypes = model.WorksMatrix[fromNode];

    if (nodeWorkTypes.Contains(3))
        return 1;
    return 0;
});

routing.AddDimension(cristalliCallBack, 0, 100, true, "cristalli");
```

######################### EDIT 3 #######################

Something like this? It seems to work,

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.MaxStops.Length; i++)
{
    var a = solver.MakeIsGreaterCstVar(meccanicaDim.CumulVar(routing.End(i)), 0);
    var b = solver.MakeIsGreaterCstVar(gommeDim.CumulVar(routing.End(i)), 0);
    var c = solver.MakeIsGreaterCstVar(cristalliDim.CumulVar(routing.End(i)), 0);

    IntVarVector abc = new IntVarVector();
    abc.Add(a);
    abc.Add(b);
    abc.Add(c);

    solver.Add(solver.MakeSumLessOrEqual(abc, 2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of:

- create one dimension per worker type.
- Increase it accordingly at each node
- on the end of the vehicle route:

  - use Solver.MakeIsGreaterCstVar(cumul_var_for_worker_type_n, 0) on each dimension to create one Boolean variable per worker type indicating if this worker type was used on the route.
  - Solver.Add(solver.MakeSumLessOrEqual(bool_var_array, 2));

Comment: Thank you @laurent for your answer, I have edited my question for further help.

Comment: You need the cumul var of the end of the route for worker n.

Comment: @laurent I have a similar problem, would it be possible to see a code example? Unfortunately I am unable to implement what you have suggested